# open new view controller from UIViewCell

Tags: xcode

// In UITableViewCell
// when I tab on screen it says "open image
2017-11-22 13:15:31.023129+0530 chat[1376:265960] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        print("open image")
        let sb =  UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc : openimageinfullscreen = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "openimageinfullscreen") as! openimageinfullscreen
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Just try self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: in UITableViewCell.  its not allowing me to use self.present.  it says "Value of type 'imagefrommyside' has no member 'present'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the top presented view controller and then present.
Try this.

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }
    return nil
}


func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    print("open image")
    let sb =  UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : openimageinfullscreen = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "openimageinfullscreen") as! openimageinfullscreen
    self.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

On a separate note, You shouldn't use class name starts with small letter. `openimageinfullscreen` class should be `OpenImageInFullscreen`